# Windows Phone 8.1 show nearby places on map c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I have create one windows phone app. In this app, I am using `MapControl` to show user **current** location on map.

```
xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"

<Maps:MapControl Grid.Row="0" Name="myMap" LandmarksVisible="True" TrafficFlowVisible="True" PedestrianFeaturesVisible="True">
</Maps:MapControl>
```

When user start the app, it show his/her current location. Here I want to show nearby places such as restaurant, petrol pumps and all others available on maps. In map control you can see I have added `LandmarksVisible="True"`. But it is **not** showing all the places. When I start default **Maps** app provided by Microsoft in my phone, it shows me all the places around me. But in my project I can't see.

> Note: I have also added MapServiceToken to myMap.

**How can I show nearby places ?**

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to do with just a MapControl. What you need to do is to fetch POIs from some kind of API, e.g. Google Places API (perhaps Bing has something similar), parse the result and display POIs you got on the map using pushpins.